# How to get current category subcategory id in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Actually, I want to get a current category, subcategory name, and URL.

Below code is not useful...

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Tempjs',
    __DIR__
);
```

I found this code and it is working fine for some products but for some products it's not working...

```
<?php

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    $catName = $category->getName(); // to get the category name
    $catUrl = $category->getUrl(); // to get the category Url
```

Comment: Can you update your full code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following way you get Subcategories by category Id.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

$categoryId = 4;
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategorie) {
    echo $subcategorie->getId();
    echo $subcategorie->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$category->getId();
$category->getAllChildern();
```

Comment: why registry is working for some products but for some products its not working